# unwind segue not appear in interface build while giving exit action

Tags: ios, xcode, interface, builder

In my Xcode interface builder, I'm not finding unwind-segue exit action. what is the problem in this case?

[image: attached image for more information]

Answer (score 0):

The list of segues available in that **Exit** panel is populated based on the unwind segues you have defined as `@IBActions` in your *other* view controllers, for example:

`@IBAction func unwindFromExampleViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
}`

This tells iOS that the `UIViewController` with this action in it (let's call it ViewControllerA) is ready to handle the unwind from the `UIViewController` in your screenshot (ViewControllerB).

Have you implemented such an action in another VC yet? Once you've have that in place (in one or more VCs), you'll be able select 'unwindFromExampleViewController' from the list of Exit options for ViewControllerB.

FYI: you can define the same unwind action in multiple VCs if you need to; iOS will pick the 'nearest' one to unwind to when it gets called.

You can find more details on using unwind segues in [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them).